# How to put an asynctask inside loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Actually what i want to do is run an asynctask inside a loop with different values. So, once the currently running asynctask finishes-it will start the asynctask again with another value and it will continue till the loop ends.

Here, the first asynctask needs to start as soon as its called and the next ones will not start before the previous asynctask finishes.

The code will be something like:

```
Myasync mAsync = new Myasync();

for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++)
{
  mAsync.execute(i);
}
```

How to do it? :-)

Comment: Do you want to do some things on `UI thread` when every `AsyncTask` completed?

Comment: @Yuriy Kolbasinskiy: nope, i dont need to do anything in UI thread after each asynctask completion.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest something like this in your doInBackgroundMethod:

```
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i< urls.length; i++){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[i]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                result.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            result.add(null);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice the `String... urls` parameter

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Shaon Hasan: If this worked for you, can you please mark this as the accepted answer?